# Unable to add breakpoints in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, android-studio-2.3

There are no red dots appearing whenever I click on any line of codes. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
There are no red dots appearing whenever I click on any line of codes
```

This is probably because you disable the `Show Gutter Icons`. You can enable it by checking it from `View -> Active Editor -> Show Gutter Icons`:

[image]

You can show the border of Android Studio by exiting the `Full Screen Mode` via `View -> Exit Full Screen`